# computing Gelman-Rubin Rhat/psrf diagnostic; memory concerns

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, convergence, rjags

My collaborator and I are finding that when we try to run `coda::gelman.diag()` on our model fit often leads to memory problems. We can obviously adjust this with thinning and burnin to some extent, but wondering what shortcuts might be available to us. We lose the "multivariate Rhat," but it looks like JAGS is creating an output (`rjags` and `R2jags`) `my.model.fit$BUGSoutput$summary` with an estimated Rhat for each monitored parameter.... is this likely sufficient?

If all of the single-variable Rhat estimates in the `BUGSoutput` are below our target value (say 1.1) are we being anti-conservative in any way? Is there a reason to call `coda::gelman.diag()` in addition to this (`gelman.diag` also estimates the upper confidence limit on Rhat)?

Are there good rules of thumb to allow us to both include a long enough chain for high effective sample size, but also avoid memory limitations with `coda::gelman.diag*()`?